# Not able to cover code coverage for Delete_Content_Document__e on Delete Content Document sobject

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage

We have one trigger in org on sobject type Delete Content Document. I am not sure what is this object and how to create its record in test class.I am not able to write test class for it.

Please find below code of trigger:

```
trigger DeleteContentDocumentTrigger on Delete_Content_Document__e (after insert) {
    List<ContentDocument> contentDocumentList = new List<ContentDocument>();
    List<Attachment> attachmentList = new List<Attachment>();
    List<eLicense_Attachment__c> eLicenseAttachmentList = new List<eLicense_Attachment__c>();
       
    for (Delete_Content_Document__e event : Trigger.New) {
        if (event.Content_Document_Id__c != null) {
            contentDocumentList.add(new ContentDocument(id = event.Content_Document_Id__c));
        }
        if (event.Attachment_Id__c != null) {
            attachmentList.add(new Attachment(id = event.Attachment_Id__c));
        }
        if (event.eLicense_Attachment_Id__c != null) {
            eLicenseAttachmentList.add(new eLicense_Attachment__c(id = event.eLicense_Attachment_Id__c));
        }
   }
    
    delete contentDocumentList;
    delete attachmentList;
    delete eLicenseAttachmentList;
}
```

Please find below test class:

```
@isTest
public class DeleteContentDocumentTriggerTest {
    
    public static testmethod void test_contentDoc(){
        Test.startTest();
          //try{
    Global_Settings__c globalSettings = new Global_Settings__c(Name = 'Default', Disable_Triggers__c = true);
        if(globalSettings != null) insert globalSettings;
        Account acc = OH_Utility_UnitTestData.createTestAccount();
        insert acc;
        Blob beforeblob=Blob.valueOf('Unit Test Attachment Body');

        ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
        cv.title = 'test content trigger';      
        cv.PathOnClient ='test';           
        cv.VersionData =beforeblob;          
        insert cv;             
                                                
         List<ContentDocument> documents = [SELECT Id, Title, LatestPublishedVersionId FROM ContentDocument];

        ContentDocumentLink contentlink=new ContentDocumentLink();
        contentlink.LinkedEntityId=acc.id;
        contentlink.ShareType= 'V';
        contentlink.ContentDocumentId=documents[0].Id;
        contentlink.Visibility = 'AllUsers'; 
        insert contentlink;
    
      
         delete documents;
        
         delete contentlink;
         Delete_Content_Document__e dc = new Delete_Content_Document__e();
       // EventBus.publish(dc);
            
        //}
        //catch(Exception e){}
        Test.stopTest();
    //insert dc;
    }

}
```

It is not covering trigger at all.

Answer (score 1):

That object is a platform event.

You can view that in Setup > Platform Events.

The trigger is written on insert and it is likely not getting covered because  of the commented line in the test class

```
//EventBus.publish(dc);
```

which will invoke this trigger. You should uncomment this line an run the test.

Make sure to pupulate details like `Content_Document_Id__c` and `Attachment_Id__c` after creating the instance of the event.

It may fail if it encounters any error but the trigger will be at least 1% covered so you will know that it is being called, and work on the errors.

If your test fails before the `EventBus.publish(dc)` then you should first work on solving those issues. I recommend using `testSetup` to create test data.

Comment: I had not commented EventBus.publish(dc) line earlier while testing but still trigger was not getting covered. But creating test data in setup and populating Content_Document_Id__c and Attachment_Id__c field helped to cover code.Then I removed  comment from  EventBus.publish(dc) and ran test class and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

// This test class covered 100% code for Delete_Content_Document__e trigger

@isTest
public class DeleteContentDocumentTriggerTest {
    @testSetup static void createTestData() {
         Global_Settings__c globalSettings = new Global_Settings__c(Name = 'Default', Disable_Triggers__c = true);
        if(globalSettings != null) insert globalSettings;
        Account acc = OH_Utility_UnitTestData.createTestAccount();
        insert acc;
        Blob beforeblob=Blob.valueOf('Unit Test Attachment Body');

```
    ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
    cv.title = 'test content trigger';      
    cv.PathOnClient ='test';           
    cv.VersionData =beforeblob;          
    insert cv;             

     List<ContentDocument> documents = [SELECT Id, Title, LatestPublishedVersionId FROM ContentDocument];

    ContentDocumentLink contentlink=new ContentDocumentLink();
    contentlink.LinkedEntityId=acc.id;
    contentlink.ShareType= 'V';
    contentlink.ContentDocumentId=documents[0].Id;
    contentlink.Visibility = 'AllUsers'; 
    insert contentlink;

    Attachment att=OH_Utility_UnitTestData.createAttachment(acc.id);


    eLicense_Attachment__c elicAtt=OH_Utility_UnitTestData.createTestELicense();
    insert elicAtt;


}
public static testmethod void test_contentDoc(){
    Test.startTest();
   ContentDocument document = [SELECT Id, Title, LatestPublishedVersionId FROM ContentDocument limit 1];
   Attachment att=[select id from Attachment limit 1];
    eLicense_Attachment__c elicAtt=[select id from eLicense_Attachment__c limit 1];
    Delete_Content_Document__e dc = new Delete_Content_Document__e(Content_Document_Id__c=document.Id,Attachment_Id__c=att.id,eLicense_Attachment_Id__c=elicAtt.id);
    Database.SaveResult sr=EventBus.publish(dc);       
    Test.getEventBus().deliver();       
    Test.stopTest();

}
```

}